# How to reference positions in php nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$myarray` like:

```
Array (
  [45] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 45
    [response_id] => 2
    [question_id] => 1
    [choice_id] => 2
  )
  [46] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 46
    [response_id] => 2
    [question_id] => 2
    [choice_id] => 4
  )
  ...
)
```

How can I reference the positions of this array?
For instance getting the first, second, . . . position of the array.

The only way that seems to work is if I explicitly say

```
$myarray[45]->choice_id
```

But I don't always know the numbers and I want to reference the positions. Is there a way to reference the first position as:

```
$myarray[0]->choice_id
```

Thanks

Comment: You could use `array_values` to reset the keys with the usual zero indexed sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it seems like you might as well reindex the array with `array_values`. Since the key is the same value as the id property in each of the inner objects you won't be losing any data.

But in general if you want to pick arbitrary positions in the array while preserving its keys, one way is to construct an iterator with it. For example:

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($array);
$iterator->seek(2);               // go to position 2 (regardless of key)
$value = $iterator->current();
```

Of course, if you specifically want the first item, the easiest way is `$value = reset($array);`